# Handling differing naming conventions in json deserialization

Tags: c#

If I have a class such as:

```cs
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

...and a route-method which gets sent this type of data:

```cs
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Mvc.Route("/add-person")
public JsonResult AddPerson (Person person) {
    addPerson(person);
    return Json(new { type = "success" });
}
```

Can I configure the route such that it will work with json data which is posted in camel-case?:

```
{
  "name": "test name",
  "age": 1
}
```

Comment: This should already work OOTB. Are you having any issues posting the sample JSON?

Comment: Do you get any exception when trying to post json in camel-case? Please give some detailed error information. As @jcruz mentioned: this should work ootb

Comment: @jcruz thanks - this is my mistake I'm afraid, I thought I had tested this with camel case but evidently not, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as it is.

If you want to customize the JSON Properties, this is a good point to start at: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonPropertyAttribute

Also, you should be able to use the native `DataContract` Attributes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Many thanks - I had not tested this out correctly and it does indeed work as is